# Recommend a ZIP assembly for Silverlight 4

Tags: compression, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, zip, deflate

I've been using the [Silverlight version of #ziplib (SharpZipLib)](http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/) but it seems seriously flawed because the `DeflateOutputStream` always produces 2 bytes (120, 156) for *any* input (hell of a compression algorithm ;) so I cannot use that one. What's more it seems like that latest release is almost 2 years old now.

Any recommendation for a free (to be used in a commercial product) assembly that supports deflating streams?

Edit: The [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) site says Silverlight support is deferred to the next release. Considering last *release* was last year and an alpha is in 'da hood' now we are likely to see something fruitful coming soon :)

Comment: Did you post this issue to the developers of Silverlight SharpZipLib? It sounds either like a bug or a misuse.

Comment: @Ron: Since this library is not being actively developed the likely hood of getting a solution to a bug is fairly low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon me, but I was wrong about Silverlight SharpZipLib. It works fine if you remember to call `Flush` and `Close` on the `DeflateOutputStream`. I was using a `MemoryStream` for backing so I could compress data that I would upload to server. Thinking the data was lost if the stream was closed I didn't do so on purpose. That was until I discovered `byte[] MemoryStream.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of Silverlight I prefer [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), however there is no Silverlight equivalent.

The only other alternative to the SharpZipLib for Silverlight is to Silverlight's own Zip file decompression.  However its really just designed for accessing resources in Xaps.

Comment: Actually DotNetZip has been compiled for SL4, by the community.  But you're correct that there is no "official" SL4 release of DotNetZip, yet.

Comment: @Cheeso: That's really good to know. Has that been compiled unmodified?  Where can I find out more?  DotNetZip has IMO a much better API to work with than SharpZipLib.

Comment: Not unmodified. The person used conditional-compilation to remove a few portions of the code that were unnecessary or unwanted.  One example is the self-extracting archive generation stuff, if I am not mistaken.  That accounted for about 50% of the size of the overall DotNetZip library, so it's a big win to remove it from the SL4 version.  He said, other than removing that stuff, it was a straightforward, mechanical operation to compile it.

Comment: @Cheeso: Excellent I'll have a stab at that myself.